# DataTable.GetChanges() not working as expected

Tags: vb.net

vb.Net 4.6.1 - 
Windows Forms App

I am trying to pick up some changes to a datatable on a form and I'm having some issues. I've gotten the functionality to work fine on a test form but I can't figure out the issue on my large form.

Assume I have a windows form with a combobox that shows a list of IDs and one textbox that holds the detail for the Id. The detail.text property is bound to a dataadapter. My problem is that when I change the text in the textbox and then check getchanges I see no changes.

I put a button on the form to check the datatable values on demand and they are changing but for some reason changes aren't detected.

1. Load the form, choose an Id in the combobox and the detail is loaded in the textbox.
2. Press the button and see the original value:

   MessageBox.Show(DsSIngleJob.apGetSingleJob.Item(0).detail)
   MessageBox.Show(DsSIngleJob.apGetSingleJob.Rows(0).Item("detail"))
3. Change the text in the textbox.
4. Press the button and the messageboxes show the new value.
5. Test for changes and none are found:

   ApGetSingleJobBindingSource.EndEdit()

   Dim JobChanges As DataTable = New DataTable

   JobChanges = Me.DsSIngleJob.apGetSingleJob.GetChanges

   MessageBox.Show(JobChanges.Rows.Count.ToString)

If, instead of changing the text on the form, I write it directly to the datatable before I EndEdit then the changes are picked up:

```
 DsSIngleJob.apGetSingleJob.Rows(0).Item("detail") = "NewValue"
```

Since I have it working on a test form it has to be some issue with the main form or the associated dataadapter but I've been messing around with this all day and I can't get it to work. If anyone has something worth checking that would be great. I checked the form for any applychanges or loads after the textbox is manually changed but I didn't find anything.

Comment: Call the form's `Validate` method first, then call the BindingSource's `EndEdit` method. I'm fairly sure that I found in the past that that forced pending changes to be committed.

Comment: By the way, why are you creating a new `DataTable` and assigning it to the `JobChanges` variable and then immediately discarding it when you assign the result of `GetChanges` to that same variable?  Why do `Dim JobChanges As DataTable = New DataTable` and `JobChanges = Me.DsSIngleJob.apGetSingleJob.GetChanges` rather than `Dim JobChanges As DataTable = Me.DsSIngleJob.apGetSingleJob.GetChanges`? Don't create new objects unless you actually intend to use them.

Comment: I don't have to call Validate on my test form and it works fine. I'll give it a go but it seems that if it's required I'd have to do it in my working model as well. Thank you.

Comment: If you have data bound to a WinForms control then there's a `Binding` object controlling the flow of that data. That `Binding` has a `DataSourceUpdateMode` property that is set to `OnValidation` by default but can be changed to `OnPropertyChanged` or `Never`. Assuming that it is the default in your case, I believe the situation is that data will be pushed from the control to the bound `DataRowView` when the control raises its `Validated` event and from the `DataRowView` to the `DataRow` when `EndEdit` is called. TBC

Comment: Both that event and that method call will occur implicitly upon certain navigation but can also be forced. Call `Validate` will force the event to be raised and calling `EndEdit` on the `BindingSource` will call `EndEdit` on the `DataRowView`. If you call `EndEdit` implicitly or explicitly before the `Validated` event is raised either explicitly or implicitly then you won't see the new data in the `DataRow`.

Comment: I can see the new data in the datarow just fine but when I use GetChanges nothing is returned. So I make a change, I can see the change in the datarow, the data saves just fine but GetChanges still shows nothing. Works fine in my test form and not on my production form. On the test form I don't call Validate, I haven't changed the DataSourceUpdateMode and GetChanges works just fine.

Comment: If that is really the case then something in your project it's corrupt. GetChanges does what it does so, if it's not, something it's broken.

Comment: I'm rebuilding the entire form from the original method by method. GetChanges is working now but I have about 20 more methods to move over. Might be able to isolate it this way. Thank you.