# Updated value in CheckBox is not updating the DataTable; when I use DataTable.GetChanges I don't get anything

Tags: .net, vb.net, data-binding, datatable, datasource

I'm having issues with the updated value in the CheckBox not updating the DataTable. When I use DataTable.GetChanges I get *Nothing* even though I changed the check box value by clicking on it.

This CheckBox is bound to a DataTable and it does load the values from the BindingSource. The code runs fine but **it is just not noticing the changes in the property**... at least I have not been able to get the changes by using the DataTable.GetChanges method.

Here is some of my code:

```
Public Class ManageSchedule
    Private _bsSchedule as BindingSource
    Private _dtSchedule As DataTable

    Private Sub ManageSchedule_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Try
            Dim bsCleaningPersons As BindingSource = DataAccess.GetActiveCleaningPersonsRecords()
            Dim dtCleaningPersons As DataTable = bsCleaningPersons.DataSource

            With CleaningPersonComboBox
                .DataSource = dtCleaningPersons
                .DisplayMember = dtCleaningPersons.Columns("CleaningPersonName").ToString()
                .ValueMember = dtCleaningPersons.Columns("CleaningPersonId").ToString()
            End With

            Dim bsAssignedTo As BindingSource = DataAccess.GetActiveAssignedToRecords()
            Dim dtAssignedTo As DataTable = bsAssignedTo.DataSource

            With AssignedToComboBox
                .DataSource = dtAssignedTo
                .DisplayMember = dtAssignedTo.Columns("AssignedToName").ToString()
                .ValueMember = dtAssignedTo.Columns("AssignedToId").ToString()
            End With


            _bsSchedule = DataAccess.GetSchedulesByScheduleIdRecord(ScheduleIdLookup)
            _dtSchedule = _bsSchedule.DataSource

            If Not IsNothing(_dtSchedule) Then
                    With _dtSchedule
                        ScheduleIdTextBox.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", _dtSchedule, .Columns("ScheduleId").ToString(), False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged))
                        AppointmentDateTimePicker.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Value", _dtSchedule, .Columns("AppointmentDate").ToString()))
                        CleaningPersonComboBox.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("SelectedValue", _dtSchedule, .Columns("CleaningPersonsId").ToString()))
                        AssignedToComboBox.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("SelectedValue", _dtSchedule, .Columns("AssignedToId").ToString()))
                        ArrivedLateCheckBox.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Checked", _dtSchedule, .Columns("ArrivedLate").ToString(), False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged))
                    End With
                If _dtSchedule.Rows.Count = 0 Then
                    AppointmentDateTimePicker.Value = Today
                    CleaningPersonComboBox.SelectedValue = -1
                    AssignedToComboBox.SelectedValue = -1
                End If


            End If

            NewAppointmentLabel.Visible = (Trim(ScheduleIdTextBox.Text) = "")

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & $"Stack Trace:" & vbCrLf & ex.StackTrace)

        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Sub ManageSchedule_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
        Dim dChanges As DataTable = _dtSchedule.GetChanges() 

        If Not IsNothing(dChanges) Then
            Select Case MessageBox.Show($"Do you want to save your changes before closing this form?",caption := $"Save Changes?",buttons := MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel )
                Case DialogResult.Yes 
                    If SaveChanges() = Failed Then
                        e.Cancel = True
                    End If
                Case DialogResult.No 
                    'Don't do anything, just continue closing.
                Case DialogResult.Cancel
                    'Cancel closing
                    e.Cancel = True
            End Select
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: When binding, ALWAYS set the `DataSource` last, AFTER `DisplayMember`, `ValueMember` or `DataMember`. Also, this is crazy: `.DisplayMember = dtCleaningPersons.Columns("CleaningPersonName").ToString()`. You're using a `String` literal and then going round the houses to get the same value. Just use `.DisplayMember = "CleaningPersonName"`. Similar for the other properties.

Answer (score 0):

Bind your `DataTable` to a `BindingSource` and bind that to your control(s). Call `EndEdit` on the `BindingSource` before trying to use the data in the `DataTable`.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by adding these two lines of code at the beginning of the **FormClosing** event.

```
Validate()
_bsSchedule.EndEdit()
```

Thanks in part to **jmcilhinney** in a comment on this page...
[DataTable.GetChanges() not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55366512/datatable-getchanges-not-working-as-expected)

I had searched Google and StackOverflow but must not have searched for the proper terms to find that answer.